# How to prevent words within <pre> tags from splitting on the edge?

Tags: html, css

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS 3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  color: #595959;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
 <pre>This is a test of a longer comment that continues to take up more space than a smaller comment [enter]</pre>
```

Here is an example of what's happening

[image]

Is there a way to prevent a word (in this example: "than") from being split on the edge of the `<pre>`'s set `width` of `500px`?

Also, is there a way to make a `<pre>` tag responsive to the resizing of a table? (this `<pre>` tag resides in a `<td>` of a `<table>`)

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one. They should be separate posts so that posts are most useful to the widest audience possible

Comment: I'll remember this; thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove `word-wrap: break-word;` and `word-break: break-all;` (if you use that too)

```css
table {
  width: 60%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS 3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  color: #595959;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>      
      <pre>This is a test of a longer comment that continues to take up more space than a smaller comment [enter]</pre>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @faalbane Updated with a table for responsiveness. What browser do you test this in? ... I tested in Chrome, FF, IE11 and all work

Comment: Chrome, IE9, Firefox, Safari5

Comment: Maybe my table css is interfering somehow?

Comment: @faalbane If you test with my snippet here on SO, still not working?

Comment: @faalbane You have to be able to break down  your problem and reproduce it here

Comment: @faalbane is there any additional CSS in the site that could be causing this, that you haven't shown here? I'm unable to reproduce the problem you're having on my end.

Comment: Is there any CSS you know of that could interfere in this way?

Comment: @faalbane You need to post the rest of your code. Now you at least see it does work when the `word-wrap` is removed.

Comment: @LGSon - works *with* word-wrap as well. See his initial post. Snippet runs fine as-is.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, I saw that, it is the property `word-break: break-all;` that it could be as well

Comment: @faalbane Look for this too in your existing code: `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: @faalbane Was my answer/comments to any help?